# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'attr' of undefined

Tags: highcharts

I downloaded the 1.3.1 version of Highstock and now I am getting this error in the highstock.js code. It has something to do with the scrollbar. If i turn the scrollbar off the chart and navigator render fine or if i turn off the navigator the chart and scrollbar render fine but with both turned on i get this error somewhere in this part of the code. I can run the exact same chart on the 1.2.2 version and all runs fine. Any help would be appreciated.

if (r)
                    this.drawScrollbarButton(0), this.drawScrollbarButton(1), k[e]({translateX: i,translateY: v(F + x)}), o[e]({width: j}), g = n + d, h = c - G, h < y && (D = (y - h) / 2, h = y, g -= D), this.scrollbarPad = D, l[e]({x: V(g) + G % 2 / 2,width: h}), y = n + d + c / 2 - 0.5, this.scrollbarRifles.attr({visibility: c > 12 ? "visible" : "hidden"})[e]({d: ["M", y - 3, n / 4, "L", y - 3, 2 * n / 3, "M", y, n / 4, "L", y, 2 * n / 3, "M",

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'attr' of undefined

y + 3, n / 4, "L", y + 3, 2 * n / 3]});

Comment: Please make a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) to illustrate your problem. Also try to reproduce the error mith the non minified version of Highstock. Here is an highstock example if you have not used it before, http://jsfiddle.net/2N52H/1/

Comment: check out this jsFiddle. As far as i can tell i am pushing data in to the chart but it just hangs. [jsFiddle.net/Sy2Qc/](http://jsfiddle.net/eburch/Sy2Qc/)

Comment: I really don't understand what the fiddle has to do with your question. Please update the question, for future references for other persons at least.

Answer (score 0):

You are not pushing data into the chart. You are pushing data into a variable in your global scope. When you create the chart that global variable is empty, it will then make a copy of the empty variable for Highcharts. When you push data the variable in Highcharts object remains empty.

Here is an updated example which illustrates the problem explained above:
http://jsfiddle.net/8Esve/1/

In the `data` method you need to call `this.series[0].setData(Pressure);` for instance to actually update the chart. Here is an example of that http://jsfiddle.net/8Esve/2/